# Scroll edittext in a scrollview to the top of the screen

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a below type structure,

```
<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <EditText1>
        <EditText2>
        <EditText3>
        <EditText4>
        <EditText5>
        <EditText6>
        <.......>
        <.......>
        <.......>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My problem is when I select any of the EditText, the ScrollView should scroll in such a way that the selected EditText should be moved on to the top of the screen just after the action bar, and below the selected EditText the soft-keyboard should open.

Please give me some suggestions to accomplish this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

open your manifest file of your project locate the activity in which you want the behavior you are looking for and write this as it's attribute

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

**Example**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SOMEActivity"
            android:label="@string/some_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

you can try different values for "`windowSoftInputMode`" attribute to see what exactly you want.

Comment: I have already done what you suggested, and this doesn't moves the selected EditText on to the very top of the screen.
what I want is, the selected EditText should be scrolled up and placed just after the Action Bar.

Comment: @OmiMishra, i don't think  so, that this attribute will work like that, as the ContentView is moved upward only is the selected view is not visible due to softkeyInput